# Read and Display XML File with HTML and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, html

I'm working with HTML5 and XML. I need to display the XML file (full code not only the data) without using any tags in xml file(like catalog, pre, textarea) when the button clicks.

Can anyone help me to do this..?

Thanks..

Comment: provide us the javascript code of your attempt

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "xml",
                url: "resources/jmx/participantRegistration_MultipleEventId.jmx",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.jmx-text').html(data);
                }
            });

Comment: its not working..!!!

Comment: have you tied `$('.jmx-text').html('<code>'+data+'</code>'); `

Comment: no.. i ll try this.. Thank u..

Comment: Its not working....!

Comment: how about `$('.jmx-text').html('<code>'+$(data)[0]+'</code>');`

Comment: This returns an object..[object XML Document]